# Determine if a set of points lie on a regular grid

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry

**Problem:** Suppose you have a collection of points in the 2D plane. I want to know if this set of points sits on a regular grid (if they are a subset of a 2D lattice). I would like some ideas on how to do this.

For now, let's say I'm only interested in whether these points form an axis-aligned rectangular grid (that the underlying lattice is rectangular, aligned with the x and y axes), and that it is a complete rectangle (the subset of the lattice has a rectangular boundary with no holes). Any solutions must be quite efficient (better than O(N^2)), since N can be hundreds of thousands or millions.

**Context:** I wrote a 2D vector field plot generator which works for an arbitrarily sampled vector field. In the case that the sampling is on a regular grid, there are simpler/more efficient interpolation schemes for generating the plot, and I would like to know when I can use this special case. The special case is sufficiently better that it merits doing. The program is written in C.

Comment: Let me understand your problem better: what are you assuming about your lattice basis vectors? Do they have they same length? Are they orthogonal? Are they `(1,0)` and `(0,1)`?

Answer (score 6):

This might be dumb but if your points were to lie on a regular grid, then wouldn't peaks in the Fourier transform of the coordinates all be exact multiples of the grid resolution? You could do a separate Fourier transform the X and Y coordinates. If theres no holes on grid then the FT would be a delta function I think. FFT is O(nlog(n)).

p.s. I would have left this as a comment but my rep is too low..

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure if this is what you are after but for a collection of 2d points on a plane you can always fit them on a rectangular grid (down to the precision of your points anyway), the problem may be the grid they fit to may be too sparsly populated by the points to provide any benefit to your algorithm.

to find a rectangular grid that fits a set of points you essentially need to find the [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of all the x coordinates and the GCD of all the y coordinates with the origin at xmin,ymin this should be O( n (log n)^2) I think.

How you decide if this grid is then too sparse is not clear however

Answer (score 3):

If the points all come only from intersections on the grid then the [hough transform](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hough_transform) of your set of points might help you. If you find that two mutually perpendicular sets of lines occur most often (meaning you find peaks at four values of theta all 90 degrees apart) and you find  repeating peaks in gamma space then you have a grid. Otherwise not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works in O(ND log N), where N is the number of points and D is the number of dimensions (2 in your case).

1. Allocate D arrays with space for N numbers: X, Y, Z, etc. (Time: O(ND))
2. Iterate through your point list and add the x-coordinate to list X, the y-coordinate to list Y, etc. (Time: O(ND))
3. Sort each of the new lists. (Time: O(ND log N))
4. Count the number of unique values in each list and make sure the difference between successive unique values is the same across the whole list. (Time: O(ND))
5. If

   - the unique values in each dimension are equally spaced, and
   - if the product of the number of unique values of each coordinate is equal to the number of original points (length(uniq(X))*length(uniq(Y))* ...  == N,

then the points are in a regular rectangular grid.

Comment: I know this question is old, but I was working the exact same problem (interpolating a vector field from sampled points) and was wondering if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say a grid is defined by an orientation `Or` (within 0 and 90 deg) and a resolution `Res`. You could compute a cost function that evaluate if a grid `(Or, Res)` sticks to your points. For example, you could compute the average distance of each point to its closest point of the grid.

Your problem is then to find the (Or, Res) pair that minimize the cost function. In order to narrow the search space and improve the , some a heuristic to test "good" candidate grids could be used.

This approach is the same as the one used in the Hough transform proposed by jilles. The (Or, Res) space is comparable to the Hough's gamma space.